# Create XY Event Layer using Python Script tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to create a script toool for Making XY Event layer , But having stuck with GetParameters function while running the script with an error window of "This tool has no parameters"

Here is my code

```
#Import system modules
import arcpy

import os

arcpy.env.workspace = Working

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Script arguments
Input_Table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

Output_Workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Local variables:
XY_Event_Layer = Input_Table

X Cord = "Longitude"

Y_Cord = "Latitude"

spRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

Output_Workspace = "New_Feature_Class.shp"

# Process: Make XY Event Layer
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Input_Table, "Longitude", "Latitude", XY_Event_Layer, spRef)

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(XY_Event_Layer, Longitude_and_Latitude_Points, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are created when you're adding your python script as a tool.
[image]

[image]

Once a script is added you can access its properties to edit parameters.
[image]

[image]